Android foreground service multiple notifications for same service?
I'm working on an alarm app, and the issue I'm facing is that when one alarm is ringing and a new alarm starts, the new alarm's notification replaces the existing one. I want both notifications to be displayed simultaneously without the new one canceling the previous notification.
the service code
package com.example.alarmclock.service


import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.example.alarmclock.R
import com.example.alarmclock.common.AlarmSound
import com.example.alarmclock.common.Constant.EXTRA_ID
import com.example.alarmclock.common.Constant.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import com.example.alarmclock.common.Constant.EXTRA_SOUND
import com.example.alarmclock.common.Constant.EXTRA_TIME
import com.example.alarmclock.common.Constant.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
import com.example.alarmclock.common.formatCurrentTime

import com.example.alarmclock.presentation.alarm_challenge_screen.ui.AlarmChallengeScreen
import java.util.Calendar


class AlarmsService : Service() {

    private var alarmSound: AlarmSound? = null


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {


        val id = intent?.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, 0) ?: return START_NOT_STICKY
        val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE) ?: ""
        val soundResId = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_SOUND, R.raw.default_sound)
        val time = Calendar.getInstance().formatCurrentTime()

        displayNotification(
                id,
                this,
                 "Alarm Triggered : $time",
                 "Message: $message",
                createAlarmChallengeScreenIntent(this, time, id)
        )

        alarmSound?.release()
        alarmSound = AlarmSound(this, soundResId).apply { startSound() }

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        alarmSound?.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }


    private fun displayNotification(
        id: Int,
        context: Context,
        title: String,
        description: String,

        openAlarmChallengeScreenIntent: PendingIntent
    ) {

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).apply {
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_alarm_add_24)
            setContentTitle(title)
            setContentText(description)
            setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            setOngoing(true)

            setFullScreenIntent(openAlarmChallengeScreenIntent, true)
        }.build()
        
        startForeground(id, notification)

    }


    private fun createAlarmChallengeScreenIntent(
        context: Context,
        time: String,
        id: Int,
    ): PendingIntent {
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmChallengeScreen::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time)
            putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id)
        }

        val requestCode = "openAlarmChallengeScreen$time${id}".hashCode()

        return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
    }


}


It seems the issue might be with startForeground(id, notification). Even though I'm using a different notification ID, the problem persists where the current notification gets canceled and a new one is displayed.

To show multiple notifications without replacing the older ones, you need to provide a unique ID.
val uniqueId = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()

val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID).apply {
    setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_alarm_add_24)
    setContentTitle(title)
    setContentText(description)
    setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
    setOngoing(true)
    setFullScreenIntent(openAlarmChallengeScreenIntent, true)
}.build()

startForeground(uniqueId, notification)


The ID I'm using is a unique ID, so the problem isn't with the unique ID.
